# MySQL - stored procedure returns unexpected value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure(`MySQL`) that should return all user's data by user's email. Here is my stored procedure:

```
-- Change Delimiter
DELIMITER //
-- Create Stored Procedure
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` PROCEDURE GetUserByEmail( 
    IN Email VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = Email;

END//
-- Change Delimiter again
DELIMITER ;
```

However, instead of returning all data only for the user with specified email, it returns all user table. And when I run the same query without stored procedure it returns only data for the user with specified email. Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'username@email.com';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s because email it´s allways = to Email (the column names are not case sensitive) You should change it to something like this:

```
-- Change Delimiter
DELIMITER //
-- Create Stored Procedure
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` PROCEDURE GetUserByEmail( 
    IN My_email VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = My_email;

END//
-- Change Delimiter again
DELIMITER ;
```